# How do you fill a Callable attribute via clone?

Tags: raku

```
class Foo {
    has &.bar;
    has @.quux is required;
    method clone { nextwith :quux(@!quux.clone) };
    # as per <https://docs.perl6.org/type/Mu#method_clone>
};
my $f = Foo.new(quux => []);
my $f-clone = $f.clone(bar => sub { die });
# Foo.new(bar => Callable, quux => [])
```

but should be

```
Foo.new(bar => sub { #`(Sub|94789546929784) ... }, quux => [])
```

Adding `:bar(&!bar.clone)` to the `nextwith` call does not help.

Comment: You could try forward the  arguments to `clone` to `nextsame`, for example like this:   `method clone(*%twiddles) { nextwith(:quux(@.quux.clone), |%twiddles)`

Comment: that does work, please convert to answer so I can accept

Comment: @HåkonHægland Converted. (Actually I saw the same thing independently but I like to have a nice answer so it takes me a while. In this case I couldn't find suitable doc references to several things including `%_`. It took me a while to give up.)

Comment: @raiph Excellent :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`nextwith`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/functions#index-entry-dispatch_nextwith) "calls the next matching candidate with arguments provided by users". You're only passing a `:quux` argument in the `nextwith` call.

Unless you add an explicit slurpy hash parameter (eg. `*%foo`), all methods have an implicit `*%_` in their signature:

```
say .signature given method ($a, $b) {} # (Mu: $a, $b, *%_)
```

So by default all named arguments are slurped into `%_`. A common idiom is to pass these on:

```
method clone { nextwith :quux(@!quux.clone), |%_ }
```

The above will pass arguments provided to the `$f.clone` call onto the `nextwith`'d `clone` call.

> Adding `:bar(&!bar.clone)` to the `nextwith` call does not help.

That will be *instead of* the `:bar` argument passed in the `$f.clone` call. The `&!bar` in the original object contains the `Callable` type object.